# Column-slicing method that works on both numpy arrays and pandas dataframes

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

### Example Problem

Suppose that I have to write a function that returns the first column of a datatable object, but that I don't know in advance whether this object will be a numpy 2D-array or a pandas 2D-dataframe.

### Tried thus far

The following function works for numpy arrays, but not for pandas dataframes:

```
def get_first_column(array_or_dataframe):
    return array_or_dataframe[:, 0]
```

The following function works for pandas dataframes, but not for numpy arrays:

```
def get_first_column(array_or_dataframe):
    return array_or_dataframe.iloc[:, 0]
```

### Summary

Is it possible to write a single expression for column-slicing that works on both numpy arrays and pandas dataframes?

Comment: Check with `type()` and use with `IF-ELSE`?

Comment: why don't you just pass the np array of the df? e.g. in calling code : `get_first_column(df.values)`  basically you either want the type check logic in or out of this method

Comment: @EdChum   That sounds indeed like the easiest solution if there's no slicing expression that is compatible with both numpy arrays and pandas dataframes.

Comment: I don't think so, the thing here is that they are similar but different data structures so you have to perform some kind of type checking in or out of this method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

***option 1***
`np.asarray`

```
def get_first_column(array_or_dataframe):
    return np.asarray(array_or_dataframe)[:, 0]
```

***option 2***
`try`

```
def get_first_column(array_or_dataframe):
    try:
        return array_or_dataframe[:, 0]
    except:
        return array_or_dataframe.iloc[:, 0]
```

---

***demonstration***

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

print(get_first_column(df))

print(get_first_column(df.values))

[1 3]
[1 3]
```